# Linux (CentOS) default FTP (SFTP) Log File?

Tags: logging, ftp, centos, sftp, redhat

I'm on `CentOS v6.4` and using its native FTP Server, which i suppose is `sftp`. *(Am i right?)* Now i can use FTP well. But i need to log the actions taken by Users.

Logs for the actions, such us, who logged in, who modified which files, who deleted which files .. etc the basically important actions, you know.

So my simple questions would be:

- Where & how can i access/check the FTP Logs from Server, please?
- Can it even be done with default `SFTP`? *(Do i need `vsftpd`?)*

In short words, what is the best & simplest way to get the FTP Logging, please?

Comment: Vsftpd is the default ftp server for red hat and by extension centos. You may be interested in the log_ftp_protocol option in /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

Comment: It is `sftp`, but not about `vsftp` now in CentOS. So i can not look into `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using sftp that's activated through ssh config your sftp access logs will be in /var/log/secure

I do not think you will be able to get details around the exact operations they've done without increasing auditd logging.